# Complexity of maximizing the number of models in a parametric formula

Tags: sat, counting-complexity

Let $F(x,y)$ be a propositional formula where $x$ and $y$ are vectors of Booleans. We want to maximize over $x$ the number of models of $F$ over $y$. As a decision problem, this becomes: given $F(x,y)$ and $N$, is there an $x$ such that the number of $y$ such that $F(x,y)$ exceeds $N$ — $\#\{y \mid F(x,y)\} \geq N$.

This problem is in $\mathrm{NP}^{\#\mathrm{P}}$, but I have not found it discussed in the literature. There are a few old posts here ([Do we know whether P^#P = NP^#P?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20119/do-we-know-whether-pp-npp), [Is $coNP^{\#P}=NP^{\#P}=P^{\#P}$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/is-conp-p-np-p-p-p)) that discuss possible relations between $\mathrm{P}^{\#\mathrm{P}}$ and $\mathrm{NP}^{\#\mathrm{P}}$, but nothing much conclusive.

I'm wondering if this problem has a name and if there are results on it.

Comment: Is the problem complete for $\text{NP}^\text{#P}$?

Comment: I have no idea. Comparison "greater than $N$" seems a bit weak for that to be true.

Comment: The decision problem is in $\mathrm{\exists PP=NP^{PP[1]}}$. This might well be a strict subclass of $\mathrm{NP^{\#P}=NP^{PP}}$.

Comment: Notation issue: is $\mathrm{X}^{Y[1]}$ the class where $X$ is allowed to make only a single call to $Y$ during one execution?

Comment: I'm thinking it is $\mathrm{NP}^{\mathrm{PP}[1]}$-complete.

Comment: Yes, that’s what the notation means. And I think you are right, the problem looks like it is $\mathrm{NP^{PP[1]}}$-complete.

Comment: Are there any results known about $\mathrm{NP}^{\mathrm{PP}[1]}$?

Answer (score 2):

The decision problem is $\exists \mathsf{PP}$-complete and this class is equal to $\mathsf{NP}^{\#\mathsf{P}}$. See [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51050/what-is-known-about-mathrmnp-mathrmpp1) and [this preprint](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03586193v1).