# What is known about $\mathrm{NP}^{\mathrm{PP}[1]}$?

Tags: counting-complexity

Following early discussion on [Complexity of maximizing the number of models in a parametric formula](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51043/complexity-of-maximizing-the-number-of-models-in-a-parametric-formula) it seems that the problem discussed is equivalent to a complete problem in $\mathrm{NP}^{\mathrm{PP}[1]}$, that is, the class of problems solvable in nondeterministic polynomial time with at most one call to a $\mathrm{PP}$ oracle (a $\mathrm{PP}$ oracle accepts if at least half of its nondeterministically possible runs accept).

I've not seen this class mentioned in the literature, but I probably missed something. I was wondering what is known about it.

Answer (score 6):

Theorem 4.1 (ii) in J. Torán, [*Complexity Classes defined by Counting Quantifiers*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/116825.116858): $\exists \mathsf{PP} = \mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{\# P}}$ (and thus $= \mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{PP}[1]}$).

I also have a short, propositional model theoretic [proof](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03586193) of this, check it out.

Comment: @davidmonniux can you provide your proof?

Comment: Done. Feel free to comment.